# Exception in urls.py

Tags: python, regex, django, url

I have spent lot of time to trace my error but i could not find can anyone please trace out where the error is?

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET

Request URL: [http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/archives]

Django Version: 1.4.1

Python Version: 2.7.3

Installed Applications:

('django.contrib.auth',

 'django.contrib.contenttypes',

 'django.contrib.sessions',

 'django.contrib.sites',

 'django.contrib.messages',

 'django.contrib.staticfiles',

 'django.contrib.admin',

 'taggit',

 'blog')

Installed Middleware:

('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',

 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',

 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',

 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',

 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  89.                     response = middleware_method(request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/middleware/common.py" in process_request
  67.             if (not urlresolvers.is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in is_valid_path
  531.         resolve(path, urlconf)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  420.     return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  300.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  300.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  196.         match = self.regex.search(path)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in regex
  162.                 compiled_regex = re.compile(self._regex, re.UNICODE)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py" in compile
  190.     return _compile(pattern, flags)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py" in _compile
  242.         raise error, v # invalid expression

Exception Type: error at /blog/archives
Exception Value: unexpected end of pattern
```

and here goes my URLS.PY

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView

from blog.models import Post

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    url(r'^$', 
        ListView.as_view(
               queryset=Post.objects.order_by("-created")[:2],
               template_name="blog.html")),

      url(r'^(?p<pk>\d+)/$',
        DetailView.as_view(
                model=Post,
                template_name="post.html")), 
    url(r'^archives/$', 
        ListView.as_view(
                queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-created"),
                template_name="archives.html")), 
    url(r'^tags/(?p<tag?\w+)/$', 'tagpage'),                        

)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe there's an error in: `url(r'^tags/(?p<tag?\w+)/$', 'tagpage')`?
I think it should be: `url(r'^tags/(?p<tag>\w+)/$', 'tagpage')`.

Answer (score 6):

```
$url(r'^tags/(?p<tag?\w+)/$', 'tagpage'),
```

replace character **?** with **>**

Comment: thanks for your reply .. ya i replaced it but still the error is same ( "unexpected end of pattern)

Comment: replaced url(r'^tags/(?p<tag?\w+)/$', 'tagpage'),as url(r'^tags/(?p<tag>\w+)/$', 'tagpage'),

Comment: need more info for finding error. Try to delete half of urls, then another half unteel you find exact line, on which django raises error.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the `?` in place of `>`, the `p` needs to be upper case.

```
r'^tags/(?P<tag>\w+)/$'
```